# Create a RTSP stream using motion and a USB webcam

Tags: camera, home-automation, motion, ffmpeg, rtsp

I've just set up a fresh RaspberryPi (Zero W) and started installing motion, in order to receive a livestream of my (old) USB webcam (Microsoft LiveCam HD-3000). I know this is a pretty old one but after a [10 min setup](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-webcam-server/), it was ready and I got a basic but working livestream at port 8081.

I'd like to go one step further and forward this livestream to my phone via a Homebridge server and the [camera-ffmpeg plugin](https://github.com/KhaosT/homebridge-camera-ffmpeg). (it's not relevant to know the Homebridge server for my question) The configuration for this plugin looks similar to one of this examples:

```
1. example: "source": "-re -i rtsp://myfancy_rtsp_stream"
2. example: "source": "-re -f mjpeg -i http://admin:password@10.0.1.101/mjpeg.cgi  -i http://admin:password@10.0.1.101/audio.cgi"
3. example: "source": "-rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://admin:password@10.0.1.101:554/play1.sdp"
```

My problem is that this plugin seems to require a URL to a RTSP stream, unless the documentation is telling me this and it's not accepting the default motion stream link (example: `http://IP_ADDRESS:8081`)

I've really searched half of Google and the [motion documentation](https://motion-project.github.io/motion_config.html) in the last few days, but unfortunately I couldn't find the correct configuration, in order to setup a RTSP stream. As far I understood, motion is supporting RTSP meanwhile and you can import an external RTSP stream with the `netcam_url` property but since my USB webcam is connected directly with the Pi, I've no stream.

Does anybody know, how to create a RTPS livestream using motion?

PS: I'd like to solve this issue without graphical interaction like for example MotionEye.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup OpenCV (C++ or Python depending on what language you prefer). OpenCV will be able to read right from the camera using capture module and there are functions you can write which will allows you to identify the motion in front of the camera.